# MySQL Error #1064 Creating a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to import this stored procedure via a .SQL file. I keep getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') BEGIN SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Cars.Color = varCarColor END' at line 1

You can see my SQL code below.  I've tried adding `$$` after the `END` then a `DELIMITER ;` but it still won't import.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `CarDealership`.`SelectCarByColor`(varCarColor VARCHAR(25))

BEGIN

SELECT * 
FROM   Cars 
WHERE  Cars.Color = varCarColor;

END
```

Comment: The `VARCHAR` data type *requires* you to specify the maximum length.

Comment: Thanks @eggyal I added the length but still no luck

Comment: You also need to terminate the `SELECT` statement with a `;` statement delimiter (i.e. between `varCarColor` and `END`).  Either that, or remove the `BEGIN ... END` compound statement block, seeing as this procedure contains only a single statement (which would also entirely avoid you having to change statement delimiter).

Comment: Figured it out needed the a semicolon `;` after the last SQL statement

Comment: Isn't that what I just said?

Comment: @eggyal Yes, but I hadn't refreshed the page to see your comment. Thanks for your help.